# Integration between Linkedin and Dynamics 2015

Tags: linkedin-api, microsoft-dynamics

I want to connect MS Dynamics 2015 with #Linkedin.  I have followed the instructions on Linkedin FAQ but that only works for 2011 & 2013 Dynamics.  The 2015 Dynamic platform does not appear to be supported.  Is that correct?

https://www.linkedin.com/static?key=installation_guide_dynamics

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: This site is for programming questions *only*.

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, that is really helpful.  Linkedin suggested that I post the question here as they were unable to answer it themselves - I'll be sure to give them your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It is already mentioned on the link that you have provided ***The solution only works with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, online and on-premise*** What you have mentioned is correct according to this [blog](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2014/07/does-microsoft-dynamics-crm-connect-to-linkedin/),as of February 11, 2015 [Comment](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2014/07/does-microsoft-dynamics-crm-connect-to-linkedin/comment-page-1/#comment-142234) states that ***he spoke with technical support recently and apparently there is no Dynamics CRM 2015 version released as of today and based on his reply there is no confirmed date***,but again in your case I think it would be better if you can contact LinkedIn support for further information